# Why is the while loop giving me a vertical column of lines instead of a horizontal one?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a histogram based on an inputted value (a double) that would print out the number of asterisks according to the inputted value.

For example, if  the value was 3.2 it would give me 3 asterisks.

Also, if the value was 0, it would give me zero asterisks.

I am using a module and a module for this problem.

```java
public void histogram(double num)
{
    double getNum = num % 10;
    double getsecondNum = getNum * 10;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= num)
    {
        if (getsecondNum < 5)
        {
            System.out.println("* " + num);
        }
        if (getsecondNum >= 5)
        {
            System.out.println("* " + num);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I am having the problem since it is a `while` loop, the lines are printing vertically instead of horizontally and including the `num` on each of the lines due to it being a `while` loop.

The program runs for values like 13.5 where it would round up, but not for lower numbers.

Comment: Look at the javadocs for `println`

Comment: I fixed the issue on the vertical printing. Do you have a suggestion on how to print the asteriks for values like 3.2 because I inputed this value and this gave me 4 asteriks.

Comment: There's a difference between `println` and `print`.

Comment: Ya, I realized. Thank you. I also fixed my entire code so my output is correct. I would take other suggestion to way to do the histogram as well.

Comment: How do i format in a comment? My code ended up line by line by line.

Comment: @Abdullah Malik You don't. If you are updating information for your question then edit and add to/modify your question. Do not add as [a] comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved code:

```
public void histogram( double num)
{


double getNum = num * 10;
double getsecondNum = getNum % 10;

int i = 1;
int k = 0;

while (i <= num)
{
    if (getsecondNum < 5)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    i++;
    
}

while (k <= num) 
{
    if (getsecondNum >= 5)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    k++;
}
System.out.print(" " + num);
}
}
```